# Error: Call to a member function guessExtension() on null

Tags: image, rest, symfony, upload

> how to edit this code for post file?  Error: Error: Call to a member function guessExtension() on null (500 Internal Server Error) Code :

**I try this:**

```
  public function ekleAction(Request $request)
    {

    //doctrini çağırdık
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //posttan gelen veriler
    $adi=$request->get('adi');
    $aciklama=$request->get('aciklama');
    $fiyat=$request->get('fiyat');
    $fotom = $request->files->get('foto');
    $kapak_foto=$request->files->get('kapakFoto');
    $kategorim=$request->get('kategori');
    $telefon=$request->get('usrtel');
    $user=$request->get('uye_id');

    $kategori= $em->getRepository("VanBundle:Kategori")->findOneBy(array('id'=>$kategorim));
    $user2=$em->getRepository("VanBundle:User")->findOneBy(array('id'=>$user));
    $serializer=$this->get('jms_serializer');

    try {
        $oto = new Oto();
        $oto->setAdi($adi);
        $oto->setAciklama($aciklama);
        $oto->setFiyat($fiyat);
        $oto->setKategori($kategori);
        $oto->setUye($user2);


        if ($telefon == null) {
            $oto->setTelefon("yok");
        } else {
            $oto->setTelefon($telefon);
        }


        $fileName2 = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $kapak_foto->guessExtension();

        $kapak_foto->move(
            $this->getParameter('brochures_directory'),
            $fileName2
        );

        $oto->setKapakFoto($fileName2);


        $images = array();
        if ($fotom != null) {
            $key = 0;


            // Çoklu Fotoğraf alma
            foreach ($fotom as $file) {
                $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

                $file->move(
                    $this->getParameter('brochures_directory'),
                    $fileName
                );
                $images[$key++] = $fileName;


                $foto = new Foto();
                $oto->addFotolar($foto);
                $foto->setAdi($fileName);
                $foto->setOto($oto);

                foreach ($images as $uploadfileName) {


                    $em->persist($oto);
                    $em->persist($foto);
                    $em->flush();

                }
            }
        }

        $data=$serializer->serialize("Başarılı",'json');

        return new Response($data,200,['content-type'=>'application/json']);

    }catch (Exception $exception){

        $data=$serializer->serialize($exception->getMessage(),'json');

        return new Response($data,200,['content-type'=>'application/json']);
    }
}

 $kapak_foto=$request->files->get('kapakFoto'); //null
```

**Note: I'm using Advanced Rest Client**

Comment: What does the original request that is sent to your controller look like? Please note that the `FileBag` of the Symfony `Request` class is exposed based on the contents of PHP's `$_FILES` superglobal. And that one is only populated with the appropriate submitted data if the request is of type `multipart/form-data` (see http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 public function ekleAction(Request $request)
    {
        //doctrini çağırdık
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();





        //posttan gelen veriler

        $data = json_decode($request->get('formData'),true);


        $adi=$data['adi'];
        $aciklama=$data['aciklama'];
        $fiyat=$data['fiyat'];
        $fotom = $request->files->get('foto');
        $kapak_foto=$request->files->get('kapakFoto');
        $kategorim=$data['kategori'];
        $telefon=$data['usrtel'];
        $user=$data['uye_id'];



        $kategori= $em->getRepository("VanBundle:Kategori")->findOneBy(array('id'=>$kategorim));
        $user2=$em->getRepository("VanBundle:User")->findOneBy(array('id'=>$user));
        $serializer=$this->get('jms_serializer');



        try {
            $emlak = new Emlak();
            $emlak->setAdi($adi);
            $emlak->setAciklama($aciklama);
            $emlak->setFiyat($fiyat);
            $emlak->setKategori($kategori);
            $emlak->setUye($user2);


            if ($telefon == null) {
                $emlak->setTelefon("yok");
            } else {
                $emlak->setTelefon($telefon);
            }


            $fileName2 = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $kapak_foto->guessExtension();

            $kapak_foto->move(
                $this->getParameter('brochures_directory'),
                $fileName2
            );

            $emlak->setKapakFoto($fileName2);
            $images = array();
            if ($fotom != null) {
                $key = 0;


                //burası şuani için array değil
                // Çoklu Fotoğraf alma
                foreach ($fotom as $file) {
                    //  $file = $fotom;
                    $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

                    $file->move(
                        $this->getParameter('brochures_directory'),
                        $fileName
                    );
                    $images[$key++] = $fileName;


                    $foto = new Foto();
                    $emlak->addFotolar($foto);
                    $foto->setAdi($fileName);
                    $foto->setEmlak($emlak);

                    foreach ($images as $uploadfileName) {


                        $em->persist($emlak);
                        $em->persist($foto);
                        $em->flush();

                    }
                }
            }

            $data=$serializer->serialize("Başarılı",'json');

            return new Response($data,200,['content-type'=>'application/json']);

        }catch (Exception $exception){

            $data=$serializer->serialize($exception->getMessage(),'json');

            return new Response($data,200,['content-type'=>'application/json']);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this code :

```
  public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $foto=$request->files->get('foto');




        return new Response(var_dump(base64_decode($foto)));
    }
```

**result : string(0) ""**

Answer (score 0):

just add this attribut in your form tag:
`enctype='multipart/form-data'`

Answer (score -1):

The error message is telling you the problem, and you even identified the offending line. You should add some checking to avoid breaking your code:

```
if ($kapak_foto instanceof WhateverObject) {
    $fileName2 = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $kapak_foto->guessExtension();

    // ...
}
```

AND you should fix the source of the problem, i.e. make sure your line

```
$kapak_foto=$request->files->get('kapakFoto'); //null
```

is returning the correct object.

Comment: kapakFoto it means cover photo. I try $kapak_foto instanceof File.
Not working. I need your help

Comment: There's no way your statement will yield an object of type File. Try following the docs to achieve what you want: http://symfony.com/doc/master/controller/upload_file.html  You are manually doing some of the work that symfony will do for you if you would use symfony forms.

Comment: I don't want to use symfony forms

Comment: OK, then you will need to manually turn the output of the request->files->get() function into a file object. Your code does not do that. Based on your original question, your first step will be to get a non-null result from that function. Why are you getting null?